# ASP.Net Drag and Drop DataGrid rows

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I've been searching the web for this for a while but can't find anything useful.

I need a grid that allows dragging and dropping of rows from the client side. Which will fire an event so I can change a value (the item order) in the database.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm a bit vague with the question because I've got nothing set up for this yet so don't have any known limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to figure it out, but I finally implemented it:

1. Use the TableDnD jQuery plugin to allow drag & drop the GridView rows in the client side: http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/
2. Implement the following solution to get the new row order in your server side and finally take the changes to the database: http://aspdotnet-example.blogspot.com/2011/10/gridview-reorder-row-drag-and-drop.html

Let me know if something is not clear enough.

Comment: gave you the answer for the implemented example.

The JQuery plugin is very simple to use, thanks.